# How to make a face recognition(identification and verification) program?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, facial-identification

So, I made a face **detection** program for webcam in Python using OpenCV2. But this just **detects** the face, it doesn't **recognise/identify** who it is. So, how to I train my program to recognise if it is me?
My code so far:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    check, frame = video.read()
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame,
                                          scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    for x,y,w,h in faces:
        frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('Face Detector', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also wanted to know if there was a way for the program to tell **how** many faces it is detecting?

Comment: 1- you need to collect positive images(including your face) and labels(txt file including coordinates of the related face) 2- you need to train it ( with yolo, haar etc.)

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate on the "labels" part and how do I train it? Can you recommend any webpages, or resources, etc. for training it?

Comment: Training processes are difficult to handle for custom detections. For a good training model, you will need appx. 1000 positive images, and you need to define as a rectangle where your face locate in each image. These rectangle coordinates and image names need to save in a txt file. This part will be really tough for you. After fininshing this step, you can train your own model. [Here](https://learnopencv.com/training-yolov3-deep-learning-based-custom-object-detector/) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-custom-object-detection-model-with-yolo-v5-917e9ce13208) may help you.

Comment: there are cheaper ways to (re-)identify faces. there are pre-trained networks for that. they emit a feature vector. the remainder is a database query problem. -- anyway, when asking on SO, you're expected to **do research** (literature review). if you do that, you'll find the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the pretrained openface model with opencv's dnn module, to get feature vectors from cropped face images, which can be easily compared with L2 or cosine distance

get the model from here:
https://storage.cmusatyalab.org/openface-models/nn4.small2.v1.t7

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch("nn4.small2.v1.t7")

# then, for each image:
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1./255, (96,96), (0,0,0), True, False)
net.setInput(blob)
feature = net.forward() # 128 floats

if cv2.norm(f1,f2) < 0.5:
    # SAME !!!
```